# does array indexes affects performance/memory usage if they has no value

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java and I've been wondering lately about memory consumption of huge, but partly empty array like in this case:

- I need array of unknown size- it can be 300k of values, it can be 300m, but to keep in mind it might as well keep only like 50 values,
- i'm initialising array with size of

  ```
  int values[] = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
  ```
- user generates some number of values that has to be stored in array every time given generating method is used

Is there any contraindication of using excessively huge arrays? How the size of array matters in case of performance when, say only 0,1% of that array is used vs 100% array usage?

In other words- when im calling empty array of X int values, will the JVM on initialisation reserve memory for X*(memory used to store 1 int value) even if there isn't any value stored yet?

Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: What's wrong with an `ArrayList`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider are you seriously suggesting using an ArrayList of size `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for storing `int` values? Just no.

Comment: The OP says up to 300m values; this should be fine for an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I wouldn't make sense to me to use an `ArrayList` here, since there is only one reason why OP might create such a large array, but doesn't fill it completely (as far as I see it): he prefers to access the items by their index. So an `ArrayList` is no help here. A `Map` should be more suited, with `Integer` as the key.

Comment: @Tom unless the `List` is sparse there is absolutely no reason to use a `Map`! Why do you think that you cannot access an `ArrayList` by index?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't think that, you just don't get my point. As I said, OP might prefer to access the array items by their index and this doesn't imply that he fills his array in an increasing order. So it is possibe to have the indices 1, 105423 and 43895435 filled, but the rest remains empty. So how should a list be helpful here? (And I repeat it, this is based on the assumption that OP used arrays to access items by their index)

Comment: @BoristheSpider my assumption from the question was that the indexes aren't known. So "300m" values doesn't mean 300 million values ranging from 0 through 299999999, it means 300 million arbitrary values. An ArrayList is not a good choice in this case, especially considering the overhead of storing an `int` (as an object) as compared to storing into an `int[]`.

Comment: @Tom you can use `ensureCapacity` to force the `List` to expand. It would of course be better to get the capacity right to begin with rather than resize. A `Map` would of course be good if the result is _sparse_; otherwise it would just be _slow_...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How the size of array matters in case of performance when, say only 0,1% of that array is used vs 100% array usage?

There's no such thing as an "empty array of X int values". Every element will have a value - it'll just be 0 by default. Every element will take 4 bytes, regardless of its value. Your `new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` array will take 8GB of memory.

If you want to create a sparse array, you might want to consider using a `Map` instead. However, note that while you can have an `int` array, a map would need an `Integer` type for the value - if you get outside the range of cached `Integer` values (and if you have a lot of different values) you could end up wasting a lot of space on `Integer` objects (and references to them).

Comment: Or `ArrayList`, or any kind of `List` really.

Comment: @Brandon: Well, yes to `ArrayList` - but it would be perfectly feasible to create a `List` implementation designed for sparse population.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize an array, you reserve a place in memory for it. This memory size will not change depends on the values in the array. The default value in int array is 0, so your array is not partially empty.